How to Remotely Reference Property Group in Registration
It seems to be impossible to remotely reference property groups registered from other scripts. If you try to do:
channels_list: CollectionProperty(type=ChannelsList)

it will NOT work if that property group was registered outside that script. I've tried putting the property group inside a Python class, I've tried using bl_idname, I've tried import statements, nothing works. Import statements don't work because trying to get VSCode or whatever running properly is way too complicated and error prone, so I work out of the text editor. The only way I've found is to put the property group in the same script.
Is there a way to do this, or do I have to copy paste the same Property Group into multiple scripts?
EDIT: For context, the reason I'm upset about this is because my add-on has 32 scripts and about 15-20,000 lines. And I don't want to use VS Code because I can't figure out how to get the dang thing to actually work. There's like 30 steps to setting it up and even if you follow all the instructions perfectly, it still may not work, and if it doesn't you're SOL because it's a hodgepodge of like 20 different softwares and plugins and whatnot.
EDIT: And I've tried stuff like this, and even within the same script it doesn't work. But this is how I'm remotely accessing functions. Just can't get it to work for PropertyGroup.
class PropertyGroups:    
    class ChannelsList(PropertyGroup):
        chan: IntProperty()
    
bpy.ALVA_PropertyGroups = PropertyGroups
PropertyGroupsInstance = PropertyGroups


class GroupData(PropertyGroup):
    name: StringProperty(name="Group Name", default="New Group", 
    update=CommonUpdaters.group_name_updater)
    channels_list: CollectionProperty(type=PropertyGroupsInstance.ChannelsList)

And then I try looking for the Property Group in bpy.types and in bpy.props and it's not there. And I'm not smart enough on C++ to look in the source code to figure out where bpy.utils.register_class() actually puts stuff.
EDIT: Someone in a different forum provided this solution:
pg_name = "PyOnePropertyGroup"

property_groups = [cls for cls in bpy.types.PropertyGroup.__subclasses__()]

for PropertyGroupSubClass in property_groups:
    if PropertyGroupSubClass.__name__ == pg_name 
        break
else:
    assert False, f"{pg_name} not registered"

bpy.types.Object.py_two_prop = CollectionProperty(type=PropertyGroupSubClass)


Can you talk more about why you want to accomplish this? There might be a good reason you can't do this for memory management reasons, or there might be a workaround or accepted path to get your data where you need it at registration time.

@Jakemoyo Because my add-on has 32 scripts and about 15-20,000 lines. Some of the PropertyGroup classes are needed in multiple scripts. Plus I would really prefer to keep PropertyGroups in a separate script to keep in line with the rest of the organization.

Are you able to show what your file/folder structure looks like? When you say 32 scripts does that mean 32 separate .py files or 32 functions in one huge file? I think this is an issue of how you're organizing your files.

What does VS Code have to do with anything?

@TheLabCat You're not supposed to create addons with tens of thousands of lines of code inside Blender's text editor.

@Jakemoyo Hundreds of functions across 32 separate .py files.

"I think this is an issue of how you're organizing your files." - Negative. My file structure is directly inspired by Blender's own internal file structure. If there's no way to remotely reference PropertyGroups within text editor in CollectionProperty definitions, I take this to the dev forum as feature request. Everything else can be remotely referenced from what I've seen so far.

VS Code isn’t the only IDE out there, though. Kate is a good one, Notepad++ is another, even Python’s built in one IDLE works fine for most lighter use cases. By no means am I suggesting writing an add-on in Blender Text Editor!

VS Code is by far the most common one for Blender and if I can't get that to work, the lesser known ones almost certainly won't be any easier. Plus it needs to be easy for non-developer people to develop the addon, which is why I'm making a secondary add-on just to extend the Text Editor just to help develop the addon.

@socrathien Honestly you need to just reword this question and actually describe what it is you're trying to accomplish. Like why do you need to remotely reference a PropertyGroup before registering? See XY Problem.

@Jakemoyo I'm not asking the wrong question, it seems like I'm just not in the right forum. If you had experience refactoring 20,000 line addons from Text Editor you would know exactly what I was talking about from the first line of my post. Externally referencing stuff from within text editor is a constant headache. But if you're used to much smaller, simpler add-ons, then I understand why you would be confused by the question.

"Like why do you need to remotely reference a PropertyGroup before registering?"
What? No. This is the first line of my post: "It seems to be impossible to remotely reference property groups registered from other scripts." Where did I say "before registering"? For example, one of the primary reasons I'm upset about this aside from organization is because I have nodes, sequencer strips, and objects all referencing the same property group. They used to all have to be registered inside same script. That's really dumb when you have hundreds and hundreds of custom properties to register.

If you would just do what the people trying to help you asked you to do (just show me what your script and file structure looks like) this question would have been answered awhile ago. The point of the comment section is to try to hash out what exactly your issue is, not for you to post paragraphs defending the decisions and disregarding everything everyone is asking you. Because I actually have written my own addons, with hundreds of files, with PropertyGroups registered outside of the scripts, in VSCode. And I'm pretty sure what you're asking is an easy fix.

But I can't just post any old random answer that I have a hunch might be your problem without more info first. Hence, why I come to the comments and ask for more info. But apparently you're the Blender scripting genius and I'm a little easily-confused guy who only writes simple scripts, so maybe you know best.

If you use VS Code, that explains why you're confused by my question. This would be a non-issue if I was in VS Code... My problem is exactly what I stated in the first line of the post. My file structure is of zero importance.

And I'm not just sharing my structure because 1, I can't easily do that since it's currently a 3 page long table inside a Word document and isn't up to date. Because 2, it's utterly irrelevant to this post. All anyone needs to know is that 32 .py's is the reason I wants PG's in a separate script. No one needs to see exactly how my folders are laid out.

And to clarify, my file structure is utterly irrelevant specifically because I am not in VS Code. When you work out of the built-in Text Editor, the file structure doesn't even exist at that point. It has absolutely zero bearing on functionality. It's just a theoretical table in a Word document. And I do have filler .py's in an actual folder system, but that doesn't have any relationship whatsoever to the Blender file. Meaning it's not like in VS Code or an operational add-on where you have to know your file structure for the .file imports. That's not happening here.

Someone provided this solution elsewhere:
pg_name = "PyOnePropertyGroup"
property_groups = [cls for cls in bpy.types.PropertyGroup.subclasses()]
for PropertyGroupSubClass in property_groups:
if PropertyGroupSubClass.name == pg_name
break
else:
assert False, f"{pg_name} not registered"
bpy.types.Object.py_two_prop = CollectionProperty(type=PropertyGroupSubClass)
